# How do I keep my add-in visible in Office 365?

Tags: office-js

When we add our add-in to Excel online sometimes it displays as a white rectangle. After further investigation we found that the add-in is being rendered correctly but a lot of `div` elements are created on top of it.

We were able to reproduce the issue by scrolling the browser window up and down quickly, shown in the following gif:
[image: Excel div bug]

Keep in mind that it some times loads with the divs on top, scrolling up and down just reproduces the issue.

We created a bare minimum add-in and tested again using it and obtained the same results:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title>Test Init</title>
    <script src="//appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="ms-font-l" style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;position:relative;">
<div id="app" style="height:100%"></div>
<script>
    console.log('Our script loaded...');
    Office.initialize = function () {
        console.log('Our App Initialized!!!')
    };
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

My question is, how do we make sure that our add-in stays on top of all the `div` elements that excel creates?

(So far we've seen the `div`s appear in Edge, IE, Chrome and Firefox. Both Windows and OSX)